# Is There a Windows Video Codec Common Dialog?

Tags: windows, video-encoding, codec, common-dialog

Does Windows have a common dialog to select video codecs? If there is one, how can I create one in c#? I'm asking because I'm currently developing with a plugin that seems to have included extremely dated codecs, and am not sure if the plugin is simply retrieving a list of codecs from the system. I don't have the source of the plugin, so I can't look at the source code directly.

Attached is a screenshot of the dialog:

[Screenshot http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/fb936bd413.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/fb936bd413.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like the save options dialog from Video for Windows. Specifically, I believe that's the dialog that pops up when you use the AviSaveOptions function from avifil32.dll.

You could probably call that from C# using P/Invoke if you wanted to.

The dialog does get a list of video codecs from the system. However, VfW only supports VfW codecs, not the newer DirectShow codecs. Any of the more modern codecs you might have installed on your system are going to be DirectShow codecs, more likely than not.

If you want a more modern codec, you're going to have to install a VfW version of that codec.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no directly accessible codecs list available in the form of a CommonDialog in C#.

CFP.